# Read word documents from C# and Display it Inline in browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-office, docx, doc

*Q 1.*

How can I read MS-Word documents(doc and docx) from C# without MS Office installed. I was able to read unformatted text  using stream reader. I think I can use OpenXML for docx. But what about doc? Is there some open source solution to handle it? Is using OLE32dll an option in unlicensed scenario?
Is use of IFilter a solution? havent seen anywhere any samples using it though and also not sure about its support in windows 7 and 8.

**EDIT** : I stumbled upon this [solution](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13391/Using-IFilter-in-C) and found it acceptable for my situation

*Q 2.*

I need to display the doc and docx files in my Webpage as Inline or in a partial page or even iframe. How is that possible? Is COM interoperablity the only solution to it too?

Comment: One of your related questions on the right - [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455268/reading-doc-and-docx-files-using-c-sharp-without-having-ms-office-installed-on-s?rq=1)

Comment: Your best bet is to simply install MS-Office on whatever PC your C# program resides.  IMHO...

Comment: @paulsm4 - Its on a WebServer

Comment: @Sayse - I couldnt find an answer in that link :(

Comment: The very first answer says NPOI

Comment: NPOI is not stable with DOC and so it isnt not added in NPOI site

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the redistributable Interop Assemblies from Microsoft, to read your ".doc" :

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3508

It doesn't require Office according to the description.

Comment: You can use it and distribute it. For further details, you can read the complete terms which are provided with the assemblies.

Comment: Just check this [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5302140/primary-interop-assemblies-for-microsoft-office-applications)

Comment: After further research, I've reached the same conclusion as you. Sorry but my solution will not work. If I find an other, I'll share it.